# Java ArrayList<String> inside abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class

Building a type hierarchy modelling bank accounts.

Originally just had

```
public class Account
{
  private ArrayList<String> transactions

  public void logTransaction(String transactionData)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

But now the class is extended into a hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Account
{
  private ArrayList<String> transactions

  private abstract void logTransaction(String transactionData);
}

public class ChequingAccount extends Account
{
  public void logTransaction(String transactionData)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

But I just can't figure out how to properly get at the array list with child methods?  Instructions are to leave the array list in the parent abstract class, but searching through previous answers says this is not a good practice to be doing?

Are my instructions contrary to best practices or am I missing something?

Comment: For future reference - when you do things like declare your `transactions` instance variable as `ArrayList<String>` you are coding to a specific implementation of a `List` which is generally considered bad practice. You should code to the interface so that if you need to change the underlying implementation the only code that changes is this class rather than all classes that depend on this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getters or setters are what you need :)

```
public class Account
{
  private ArrayList<String> transactions

  public void logTransaction(String transactionData)
  {
    ...

  }

  public ArrayList<String> getTransactions()
  {
    return transactions;
  }
}
```

Then in your child class you call the super.getTransactions() method.

```
public class ChequingAccount extends Account
{
  public void logTransaction(String transactionData)
  {
    super.getTransactions();
  }
}
```

Comment: If the children are the only ones who need access, it would be better to make the getter `protected`.

Comment: If the getter is `protected` that's probably fine in this case. However, for future reference be aware of the [Law of Demeter](http://www.yegor256.com/2016/07/18/law-of-demeter.html) - providing direct access to instance variables is discouraged.